# channels.list response body has no invideoPromotion object

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels

in revision of August 15, 2013 says that "The API now supports the ability to specify a website as a promoted item." reflecting details with "invideoPromotion" object.I need to get the items set.
However when i call the method as below,almost for 10 channels, none of them has the mentioned promoted item.
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id,status,snippet,brandingSettings,contentDetails,invideoPromotion,statistics,topicDetails&forUsername={CHANNEL}&key={API-KEY}
Is there a specific query parameter for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can only get your own channel's invideoPromotion settings.

[Here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqtuSRe3QLo) talking about invideoPromotion.

Also [here's a JAVA Sample code](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-java).

Comment: I realized that also.If i add "onBehalfOfContentOwner" parameter to the query and sending an authorized request.

Comment: yes, if yo are a contentOwner you can use "onBehalfOfContentOwner" to access invideoPromotion status of the channels you manage.